# Is multiplayer progress separated from single player?

Tags: mass-effect-3

During the course of multiplayer you level up characters, unlock characters and unlock equipment and so on, and I know that multiplayer is apparently tied in to singleplayer.

So, does progress made in multiplayer link to a related single player run (so if you start another play-through does that play through track its own progress of multiplayer unlocks, etc) or do you have a single multiplayer 'profile' shared by all single player runs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Progress made in multiplayer is *not* linked to a specific single player play through, but is recorded separately. Changing single player campaigns, starting a new one, etc seems to have no effect on your multiplayer progress.

More specifically, by playing multiplayer you will increase your *Galactic Readiness*, which will boost your effective strength for the end of the single player campaign, while reaching level 20 with a multiplayer character will give you the option to promote them, resetting that class and adding some *War Assets* to your single player.

Both of these effect *every* single player campaign you have already started and new ones you are yet to start (although Readiness degrades over time).

Comment: so promoting a single character will add the war asset to every one of my single player games, even ones I haven't created yet?

Comment: That's what I've found seems to indicate, yes (essentially, like the readiness score, it seems to effect your entire account with the game), but please correct me if I'm incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

the multiplayer affects the galactic readiness which makes it easier to get the best ending in singleplayer. the readiness stays the same through any sp playthrough and decays at a rate of 1% a day until it reaches 50%. 
the levels of your mp characters dont affect the readiness, but you can promote a level 20 character into single player for war asset points.